# Search for string within a question in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

When viewing questions from the web interface on a desktop, I often use "Find in Page". This is helpful in Stack Overflow when looking for variables and methods in code snippets. This would be a very useful feature in the SE mobile app.